# application configuration file path of yii2

Tags: yii2

I installed yii2 and then added gii to yii2 from [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tool-gii.html) link.

```
return [
'bootstrap' => ['gii'],
'modules' => [
    'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    // ...
],
// ...
```

];

I want to plce this code in `application configuration file` where it is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application configuration file reside in: project_name/config/web.php

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class'=>'yii\gii\Module',
    'allowedIPs'=>['127.0.0.1','192.168.1.*'],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find a file web.php which is in in the config folder located at your root app folder, the file will contain something like the following:

```
$params = require __DIR__ . '/params.php';
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'name' => 'My Cool App',//If this line exists change it to your new app name otherwise add it.
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => '_4wmrZYaMY7joBAFHrXKpEIFvs9m9S_I',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if(YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];
}
```

return $config;

Notice I've added a line: 'name' => 'My Cool App',

Hope this helps.