# Where do we configure Yii2 Queue extension in project?

Tags: configuration, yii2

I am trying to use the yii2-queue
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/usage.md

It says:

> In order to use the extension you have to configure it like the
>   following:
>
> ```
> return [
>       'bootstrap' => [
>           'queue', // The component registers its own console commands
>       ],
>       'components' => [
>           'queue' => [
>               'class' => \yii\queue\<driver>\Queue::class,
>               'as log' => \yii\queue\LogBehavior::class,
>                           // Other driver options
>           ],
>        ],         
> ];
> ```

My question is simple: In which PHP file, in which directory, should I put this code?

**Note**: I am using the Basic template.

Comment: Note that this might be a related question, not sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308289/application-configuration-file-path-of-yii2

Comment: It depends on Yii2 Template for Basic `config\console.php` for Advanced it can be one of `console\config\main.php`

Comment: I'm using Basic template. Thanks for the answers, however the "web" folder does not contain a config.php or a console.php.

Comment: Yii2 Basic Template  `config\console.php`

Answer (score 5):

For **Yii2 Basic** Template `config/console.php`

For **Yii2 Advanced** Template `console/config/main.php`

```
return [
   'bootstrap' => [
      'log',
      'queue',
    ],
    'components' => [
       'queue' => [
          'class' => \yii\queue\db\Queue::class,
          'db' => 'db', // DB connection component or its config
          'tableName' => '{{%queue}}', // Table name
          'channel' => 'default', // Queue channel key
          'mutex' => \yii\mutex\MysqlMutex::class, // Mutex that used to sync queries
          'as log' => \yii\queue\LogBehavior::class,
          // 'deleteReleased' => YII_ENV_PROD,
       ],
    ]
];
```

Refer [Yii2 Queue extension guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md)

Comment: @anroy If this answer is useful then mark as tick and upvote because it's useful to another one.

Comment: Note that basic template does not have a shared config - if you want to use queue from web, you need to configure it also in `config/web.php`.

Comment: OK... thanks. However the config/console.php has a lot of code in it. It's not clear how I would fit that single (but big) return statement into it. There is a variable $config being set and returned.

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
....

Comment: @anroy it's simple to put `queue` array in `components`.

Comment: @vishuB thanks.
In the Yii2 Basic Template, the 'bootstrap' and 'components' arrays were already populated with other things. So I added 'queue' to those arrays, as you wrote.  However now in my code where I am trying to use "queue" I get an error that it can't find "\yii\queue\JobInterface". I am declaring "use \yii\queue\JobInterface" at the top of that PHP file. Does anyone know the solution to that? Or should I create a separate question in StackOverflow?

Comment: @anroy yes, queue put in `components`.

Comment: @vishuB, I did that.  However now in my code where I am trying to use "queue", I get an error that it can't find "\yii\queue\JobInterface".

Comment: @anroy please give your `config/console.php` file.

Comment: @vishuB Here, let me know if you can see it.  https://github.com/anroy/basic-01/blob/master/config/console.php

Answer (score 0):

Add to the main.php file in backend or frond end you are using like this

    `'bootstrap'           => ['log', 'queue'],`

```
Add this to under component array

            'queue'        => [
                'class'     => Queue::class,
                'db'        => 'db', // DB connection component or its config
                'tableName' => '{{%db_queue}}', // Table name
                'channel'   => 'default', // Queue channel key
  'mutex'     => MysqlMutex::class, // Mutex used to sync queries
        ]
```

> To make it workfull you need to do same in console /config/main.php
>   file and run the command listen form documentaiton

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple to configure it on yii2 basic, add the following configuration on config/web.php file, and for yii2 advanced if you are using frontend then add in frontend/config/main.php, if you are using backend then add to to backend/config.main.php.

Just like this

```
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'htXdOInCiP6ut4gNbDO2',
            'csrfParam' => '_frontendCSRF',
        ],
        'queue' => [
            'class' => \yii\queue\<driver>\Queue::class,
            'as log' => \yii\queue\LogBehavior::class,
            // Other driver options
        ],
]
```